# Getting the time elapsed since 8am local time with boost

Tags: c++, datetime, boost, timezone

Since most DST funky stuff happens around midnight, I think it should be pretty safe to simply subtract the current time from the time "8 am", but that's not a solution I'm very comfortable with.

(in what follows it is assumed that the machine's local time is America/New_York, it's a safe assumption for my purpose)

To explain what I'm looking for, here's how I would do it in python

```
from datetime import datetime,date,time
print ( datetime.now() - datetime.combine( date.today(), time(8,0,0) ) ).total_seconds()
```

Or if I were a bit more ̶a̶n̶a̶l careful:

```
from datetime import datetime,date,time
import pytz
tz = pytz.timezone('America/New_York')  #local time is always New York
now = pytz.UTC.localize(datetime.utcnow()).astimezone(tz) # now in this timezone
eight_am = tz.localize( datetime.combine( now.date(), time(8,0,0) ) ) 
(now - eight_am).total_seconds()
```

How would I go about achieving each of those in C++ with boost?

Comment: "happens around midnight" - yes, at 2:00am to be specific.

Comment: The title states "time since 8am" but you describe that almost as a workaround in the first paragraph.  What's the underlying problem that you're trying to solve?

Comment: I don't describe "since 8am" as workaround, I describe looking at the difference between the local time and the local time at 8am as a bit of a workaround. Why? Because if one day I change 8am to midnight or one am, it'll break the code. Because if one day I want to make it "since 8am yesterday", the solution will break as well, etc.

An answer to the first way to do it (a simple difference) would actually be helpful, I'm not familiar with the boost time functions. An answer to the second way would be awesome of course.

Comment: But to be very clear, my end goal is to count the number of seconds elapsed since 8 am New York time. This really is the number I'm looking for, it's a final result, not some intermediary value.

Comment: to be <strike>careful</strike> anal you could add `is_dst=None` to the second .localize() call to assert that there is no DST transition at 8am. Also pytz docs use tz.normalize() around .astimezone(tz) (though It seems it is not necessary for conversion from utc). `datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)` also works

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer my own first part:

```
namespace pt = boost::posix_time; 
pt::ptime now = pt::second_clock::local_time();
pt::ptime then = pt::ptime(now.date(),pt::hours(8));
pt::time_duration dt = now - then;      
std::cout << dt.total_seconds() << std::endl;
```